# pchart error: Message: imageftbbox() [function.imageftbbox]: Invalid font filename

Tags: php, fonts, xampp, gdlib, pchart

I've tried a number of different ways and right now I'm being as explicit as I can. I'm using xampp on Windows 7 with PHP/pChart. In my code I have:

```
<?php
    include('pChart/pData.class');     
    include('pChart/pChart.class');  
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . 'C:\Windows');

        ...
    $Test->setFontProperties("/Fonts/tahoma.ttf",8);  
        ...
?>
```

I did include the '/' in front of the Fonts so that the library doesn't accidentaly append a .ttf which I read can happen in some cases.

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the font actually located at the place it's being called?

Comment: As far as I can tell yes it is.

Comment: What version of pChart is this? All those methods calls don't look like what you'd see in 2.0

Comment: And for what do u define "GDFONTPATH"?

Answer (score 0):

I use a few days ago pChart and got same error when i copy-paste example code from pChart documentation. Simply try to add location of font by adding full absolute path to it:

```
$font_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/libs/pChart/fonts/";
$Test->setFontProperties($font_folder."/Fonts/tahoma.ttf",8);
```

And i store pChart library in `[root]/libs/pChart/`. Of course u must be sure that u have a "fonts" folder. My code works fine with it. So i guess your mistake was in trying to allocate system fonts instead of local includes.